# Killing a "Critical Process" In Windows (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, windows, kill

What is the best way to kill a critical process?

Comment: what do you mean a "Critical Process"? Example...?

Answer (score 7):

It's critical for a reason so you probably shouldn't be killing it at all. The best way is to shut down the box lest you leave it in a dangerous state.

If you choose to ignore my warning, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/killprocess.aspx) is some sample C++ code to do it.

Comment: Ok. Well thank you for the life lesson. However, if I NEEDED to kill a system process, how would I do so.

Comment: Sorry, ixo, didn't mean to sound condescending, added a link for you.

Comment: Oh no, you did not sound condescending. You were just being quite logical and using reasoning :)

Thank you for the link kind sir.

Comment: Killing a critical system process means that the machine is pretty much hosed and can't do anything (i.e. can't authenticate users, can't create remote threads, etc). Don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

[This knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131065) describes how to do it.  You first call `SeDebugPrivilege()` to obtain the privileges to terminate processes, then you call [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx) with the `PROCESS_TERMINATE` flag to get a handle to the process you wish to terminate, and then finally you call [`TerminateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx) to terminate the process.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, do what Adam suggested.  Then watch as your machine bluescreens since you just terminated a critical process :) (btw, to be clear: Adam's suggestion is 100% accurate, it's not my intent to criticize it at all).

Why do you want to do this?  There's a reason they're called critical processes.

Comment: I recall one day I had a services control panel that was stuck so I decided to kill it from task manager - hmm what could the name be I asked myself - obviously it must be services.exe

Comment: In case you are wondering, no it isn't and the machine bluescreened

Answer (score 1):

Invoking the kill function in signal.h is one way to killing a process in C. No idea about the alternations in C++.

[Killing a Process in C](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Signaling-Another-Process.html)

Edit : Have a look on this code.

[WIN 32 API example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Kill_Application.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I love the link btw! (bookmarked)
What would be the best way via Windows API?

Comment: This looks like POSIX, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the question was how to kill critical process without BSoD. To do this you need first to remove criticality bit, and only after that call terminate function.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)